# How to Add a Custom Box in Between Two Points in HighCharts

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts, angular2-highcharts

I have looked into the highcharts documentation and cannot find a way to render a custom box in between a line connected between two data points. Here's the ref of How I want it to be created. Please suggest me a way to come up with this implementation or is this feasible to create a UI like this using Highcharts[Mock Ref](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdlJF.png)

I tried creating a box and placing it on the graph but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Highcharts SVGRenderer to create such boxes with text. Using the chart.events.renderer() callback function you can generate and update labels that will be placed between points.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'line',
    events: {
      render: function() {
        const chart = this;
        chart.series.forEach(function(series) {
          const xAxis = series.xAxis,
            yAxis = series.yAxis;

          let prevPoint;

          series.points.forEach(function(point) {
            if (prevPoint) {
              const growth = `Growth ${point.y - prevPoint.y}`,
                x1 = xAxis.toPixels(point.x, true),
                y1 = yAxis.toPixels(point.y, true),
                x2 = xAxis.toPixels(prevPoint.x, true),
                y2 = yAxis.toPixels(prevPoint.y, true),
                labelX = chart.plotLeft + x2 + (x1 - x2) / 2,
                labelY = chart.plotTop + y2 + (y1 - y2) / 2;

                            if (!point.customLabel) {
                                point.customLabel = chart.renderer.label(growth, 0, 0).attr({
                                    fill: 'white',
                                    stroke: series.color,
                                    'stroke-width': 2,
                                    zIndex: 5,
                                    r: 12,
                                    padding: 6
                                }).add();
                            }
                            
                            const labelBBox = point.customLabel.getBBox();
                            point.customLabel.attr({
                                x: labelX - labelBBox.width / 2,
                                y: labelY - labelBBox.height / 2,
                                opacity: series.visible ? 1 : 0
                            });
            }

            prevPoint = point;
          })
        });
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    data: [2, 2.5, 3, 3, 4, 5],
        lineWidth: 3,
        marker: {
            symbol: 'square'
        }
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hytckLxb/ 
**API**: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer 
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render 
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#toPixels

Comment: Thanks! I did try the same thing but looks like there was a problem with my logic as to how I was calculating the points to plot this. However, I wanted to know is there anyway to make the box similar to the one in mocks, I am not able to remove the line passing through the box

Comment: I have found a way to make the box similar by adding stroke and stroke-width properties. Thanks for your answer it helped a lot

Comment: Yes, `stroke` and `stroke-width` are properties with which in the `attr()` method you can set the appearance of the label in such a way that it looks like on the mockup. I improved the demo and also added opacity with the condition that the labels disappear after hiding the series with the legend.

Comment: HI Sorry to come back to you this late but, when I am trying to do the same thing in stencilJS, the customBoxes are not getting added to the DOM again when I switch between pages or elements. How can I resolve this problem? Rest of the data is being plotted only the custom SVG which was used to render the box is not being added